# How to customize texstudio with own textual macros, for example in sidebar

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio 2.12.16 and I want to customize the UI with some macros of my own. They consist of text snippets which should be inserted at caret position.

I do not want to use the "Macros" menu of the menu line (it takes too long to open this menu line, then find and select the macro). I would rather want the macro to be visible by textual name (not by icon!) in a toolbar or in the sidebar.

How can I do so?

It looks like this can be done in two ways but I fail to see how.

There are textual toolbars showing "part", "label", "tiny" etc, but whenever I add one of my macros it shows up with an icon instead of with a textual name.

The UI has a sidebar. There are buttons by which you can select "structure", "bookmarks", "symbols" and more (which I shall call "lists" for the purpose of this question). A solution would also be to customize this sidebar.

Comment: For a while you can use the shortcuts for the macros.

Comment: Yes. But they do not provide a (longer) textual clue what is available, as in a kind of "palette".